# In Python, how can I write to a file with a list

Tags: python, file, input, output

I need to create a program that asks the user for an input file and then creates an output file translating the input file into morse code. My problem is that when I try to output my list or anything into the output file, the program finishes, but the file is blank, I made a copy of the program and deleted almost everything and the file is then outputting properly,

This is my code

```
filenamer = input('Input the file you want to translate to morse code: ')

fileopenr = open(filenamer, 'r')

fileopenw = open('encoded.txt', 'w')

def convert_to_morse_code(letter):
    # Convert a single letter to Morse code.
    if letter == 'A':
        return '.-'
    elif letter == 'B':
        return '-...'
    elif letter == 'C':
        return '-.-.'
    elif letter == 'D':
        return '-..'
    elif letter == 'E':
        return '.'
    elif letter == 'F':
        return '..-.'
    elif letter == 'G':
        return '--.'
    elif letter == 'H':
        return '....'
    elif letter == 'I':
        return '..'
    elif letter == 'J':
        return '.---'
    elif letter == 'K':
        return '-.-'
    elif letter == 'L':
        return '.-..'
    elif letter == 'M':
        return '--'
    elif letter == 'N':
        return '-.'
    elif letter == 'O':
        return '---'
    elif letter == 'P':
        return '.--.'
    elif letter == 'Q':
        return '--.-'
    elif letter == 'R':
        return '.-.'
    elif letter == 'S':
        return '...'
    elif letter == 'T':
        return '-'
    elif letter == 'U':
        return '..-'
    elif letter == 'V':
        return '...-'
    elif letter == 'W':
        return '.--'
    elif letter == 'X':
        return '-..-'
    elif letter == 'Y':
        return '-.--'
    elif letter == 'Z':
        return '--..'
    else:
        return ''

list1 = []

def encode_word():
    print(fileopenr)
    for line in fileopenr:
        for word in line.split():
            word = word.upper()
            for letter in word:
                lists = list(letter)
                for letters in lists:
                    list1.append(convert_to_morse_code(letters))
                    
encode_word()

print(list1)

fileopenw.writelines(list1)
```

Even changing what the file is writing to be only a single word has the output file come out empty

```
fileopenw.write("apple")
```

Comment: You are trying to write list1, but list one remains empty by the time you are writting it to the file, no? It is not modified anywhere in your program.

Comment: I forgot to change it in the 'encode_word()' function where it used to say fulllist.append but I edited it just now.

Comment: Why are you splitting the lines into "words"? Not to mention that your `encode_word` function is not encoding a single word -- it is iterating over every line in the input and encoding every "word" in those lines. So the function name is misleading.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
filenamer = input('Input the file you want to translate to Morse code: ')

fileopenr = open(filenamer, 'r')
fileopenw = open('encoded.txt', 'w')

morse_code_dict = {
    'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.',
    'H': '....', 'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
    'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-',
    'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..'
}

def convert_to_morse_code(letter):
    # Convert a single letter to Morse code.
    morse_code = morse_code_dict.get(letter.upper())
    return morse_code if morse_code else ''

list1 = []

def encode_word():
    for line in fileopenr:
        for word in line.split():
            for letter in word:
                list1.append(convert_to_morse_code(letter))

encode_word()

fileopenr.close()  # Close the input file

morse_code = ' '.join(list1)  # Convert the list to a single string
fileopenw.write(morse_code)

fileopenw.close()  # Close the output file
```

Comment: Gah! Your solution has several problems. Let's start with the fact that you don't need to do `return morse_code if morse_code else ''` -- just do `return morse_code_dict.get(letter.upper(), '')`. There is also no need to split the lines into words. Nor is there any reason for the `list1` array to exist. I could go on but I think I've made my point. The only redeeming aspect of your solution is replacing the hideous `if...elif...` block of code in the O.P.'s solution with a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

The function writelines do not work like that with lists, as far as I know.

I would use the context manager and a loop. You can adapt the loop to use it with your format if so you wish.
The point is that write just append anything to the end of the file, meaning that you have to manage white spaces and breaklines yourself.

I have included white spaces and breaklines in this version, but if you want the text to be a continuous string, just comment those two lines out.

```py
morse = {
    'A': '.-',
    'B': '-...',
    'C': '-.-.',
    'D': '-..',
    'E': '.',
    'F': '..-.',
    'G': '--.',
    'H': '....',
    'I': '..',
    'J': '.---',
    'K': '-.-',
    'L': '.-..',
    'M': '--',
    'N': '-.',
    'O': '---',
    'P': '.--.',
    'Q': '--.-',
    'R': '.-.',
    'S': '...',
    'T': '-',
    'U': '..-',
    'V': '...-',
    'W': '.--',
    'X': '-..-',
    'Y': '-.--',
    'Z': '--..'}


filenamer = input('Input the file you want to translate to morse code: ')

def encode(file):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        tmp = []
        for line in f.readlines():
            for word in line.split():
                for letter in word.upper():
                    if letter in morse:
                        tmp.append(morse[letter])
                tmp.append(' ') ## If you do not want whitespace, comment.
            tmp.append('\n') ## If no linebreaks, comment
    return tmp

with open('encoded.txt', 'w') as fw:
    words = encode(filenamer)
    for word in words:
        fw.write(word)
```